# Java PrintWriter not flushing

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms, jsp

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<script language=\"JavaScript\">");
out.println("alert('Error');");
out.println("</script>");

out.println(sb);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

We are implementing a function to output an alert when an error is found in fliter by submitting (button) in one form (A).

But strangely, the results of doing document.form.submit () and button.click () are different.

If you do document.form.submit, the alert will print normally, but if you click () on the button, no alert will appear.

Why is that?

```
<form>
   <input id="btn" type = "submit" style = "display:none">
</form>


<script>
  document.getElementById('btn').click();
</script>
```

Comment: Update your question and add your javascript code...

Comment: I don't see any code regarding `form.submit()` or `button.click()`. Both are different and behave differently...Unless `onClick` in your JS code submits the form.

Comment: @Nirekin Thanks

Comment: When do you want this to be executed? When the page is loaded or on user action?

Comment: did you tried using `$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('btn').click();
});`